# Energy in a vibrating part of an engine

Tags: energy, frequency, vibrations

I have sensor data of the vibrations of the parts of an engine. I was wondering whether I could calculate how much energy a part contains in a given time window.

Now the energy of a wave given by such a discrete signal is the sum of squares of the amplitude. But intuitively this formula doesn't seem to fit the problem.

In this situation it is possible that the amplitude is contrained by how the part is fitted into the whole and intuitively I would expect that such a part if hit harder would have a higher frequency. Basically higher amplitude implies higher speed but if the amplitude is constrained this higher speed should result in higher frequency.

I am not a physicist so I would be happy to get a few pointers to which formulas govern this situation.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I could just calculate the speed at which the part moves. That should do the trick.